# Add new domain to 'My Sites' using network admin

Tags: multisite, network-admin

Over a year ago this multi-domain Wordpress was set up by myself and a colleague using the Network Admin tool. There are 5 sites on different domains and it works fine:

[image]

I now need to add further sites to this setup, but cannot for the life of me remember how it's done... I have gone into **My Sites > Network Admin > Sites** and clicked 'Add New', but this only allows me to create subdirectories. I need to add new domains to this installation.

I already have the correct server setup (Vhosts etc).

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: As far as I remember WP multisite does not yet support custom domains natively. Turn your related code/plugins inside out, not much we can do to help with memory problems. :)

Comment: I agree, but somehow it's working on the current 5 sites - really odd.

Answer (score 0):

In the rare case that someone needs this, I was able to accomplish extra sites but I had to do everything through the database (not ideal). Here's the comment I left for myself in wp_config.php:

```
 /* If you need to add more domains to this installation it is sadly a 
 * ballache as there's no way of doing it through the admin. 

 * In the database you need to edit the following tables:

 * wp_site - add a new domain row (make note of site ID)
 * wp_sitemeta - duplicate all the new domain meta data
 * wp_blogs - add a new domain here, match the site_id foreign key

 * Then you need to duplicate the following tables:

 * wp_i_commentmeta
 * wp_i_comments
 * wp_i_links
 * wp_i_options
 * wp_i_postmeta
 * wp_i_posts
 * wp_i_term_relationships
 * wp_i_terms

 * Finally go into wp_users and ensure a wp_i_capabilities and wp_i_user_level
 * exists for your new site ID. You should then be able to see and edit your
 * new domain.
```