# Is it still only possible to do multisite domain mapping with a plugin in WordPress 4.1?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

If I have a multisite subdomain install e.g. `mysite.co.uk` and I want to map another domain e.g. `mysite2.co.uk` to a new site in the same multisite install, is this only possible using a plugin or manually editing the database? When adding a new site to the network I only have the option to add `subdomain.mysite.co.uk`

This [old question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101111/add-new-domain-to-my-sites-using-network-admin) is relevant but I'm wondering if there have been more recent developments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes. But it seems that the WordPress team are moving toward encouraging the creation of networks of sites rather than simply using Multisite. I watched this video:

http://wordpress.tv/2014/07/26/john-james-jacoby-multisite-and-multi-network/

Which gives a good insight into creating a Network of sites. Each Network can have a different domain.

I'm therefore going to install [WP Multi Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/)

A slightly longer answer is yes and no. Once you have created a new site in a subdomain (in my use case) you can then go and edit the site and change the domain completely. Checkout the video for more details on what is going under the hood in the `wp_site`, `wp_blogs` and `wp_sitemeta` tables